# Opencv showing wrong width and height of image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with dimension `612x408` (widthxheight).

When I open it using opencv `cv2.imread(/path/to/img)` it shows me `(408,612,3)`.

This is not the problem

When I `cv2.imshow()` it shows the image correctly with width larger than height like a normal horizontal rectangle

I added `mouseCallback` to get the pixel position so when I put my mouse nearer to the right edge of image I get error `IndexError: index 560 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 408` although I have clicked on the image.

I searched on SO but could not find similar question

```
import cv2
def capture_pos(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        mouseX = x
        mouseY = y
        print('mouse clicked at x={},y={}'.format(mouseX,mouseY))
        h,s,v = img[mouseX,mouseY]
        print('h:{} s:{} v:{}'.format(h,s,v))
img = cv2.imread('./messi color.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.namedWindow('get pixel color by clicking on image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('get pixel color by clicking on image',capture_pos)
cv2.imshow('get pixel color by clicking on image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It's `(rows, columns, channels)`... nothing wrong with that. Same order should be used when indexing -- rows first, columns second. You got it switched around in `img[mouseX,mouseY]`.

Comment: Oh thanks! @Dan the correct code is `img[mouseY,mouseX]`

Comment: Can you post it as answer so that I can mark it since it helped me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dimensions you're getting seems correct. You can check the dimensions of the image with

```
print(img.shape)
```

You will get the image as `(height, width)` but this may be a bit confusing since we usually specify images in terms of *width x height*. This is because images are stored as a Numpy array in OpenCV. Therefore, to index the image, you can simply use `img[Y:X]` as *height* is the first entry in the shape and the width is the *second*.

Since it is Numpy array we get `(rows,cols)` which is equivalent to `(height,width)`.